# Angular Bootstrap's Typeahead CUSTOM Function

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I need to use custom search function to get result items list.

Documentation says:

```
<div class="mb-3 row">
    <label for="typeahead-config" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-auto col-form-label">Search for a state:</label>
    <div class="col">
        <input id="typeahead-config" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" />
    </div>
</div>

search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
    : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().startsWith(term.toLocaleLowerCase())).splice(0, 10))
)
```

so, how I can use my custom function when user types something?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "search" will be done in `map` operator. That filtering in the example is the "search". It filters available options used provided input as `term` and returns array or possible options to be displayed in the dropdown

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  map(term => yourCustomSearchFunctionGoesInHereWhichReturnsAnArray(term)
)
```

if `yourCustomSearchFunctionGoesInHere` returns `Observable`, just use `swtichMap` instead of `map`